# I checked all tutorials and still can't draw in texture painting

Tags: texture-painting

It's a classic problem here. I can't draw in texture painting. But I have a UV map, I checked face orientation, recalculated normals, unwraped object...

I'll redo this doughnut, it's just a tutorial, but it's driving me crazy...

I need to draw a texture for the doughnut layer.

Screenshot of my workspace
[enter link description here](http://joxi.ru/J2bwj4LTqlDVDA)

Link to the file
[enter link description here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/z9y8piv9nwmdi3s/donat.blend?dl=0)

Comment: Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have chosen here...

[image]

a texture.

If you press on the x ....

[image]

you can paint

[image]